# I can't clear the terminal in Mac OS X Lion - "terminals database is inaccessible"

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion

### UPDATE 3 - Better Solution

I kept Google'ing this until I came to a different solution. I ended up downloading the `terminfo` directory from somewhere ([I forgot where so I just posted the zip on my website here](http://hristo.oskov.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/terminfo.zip)) and replaced my current working `terminfo` directory with the new stuff.

The `terminfo` directory, for me, is located at...

```
/usr/share/terminfo
```

### UPDATE 2

[bahamat](https://superuser.com/users/60426/bahamat) helped me get to the solution. I added the following to my `.profile`...

```
TERM="xterm"
export TERM
```

... and I am still able to keep "xterm-256color".

### UPDATE

I figured out why this is happening. At one point, I changed some settings...

[image]

The default is "xterm-color" and I changed it to "xterm-256color". Is there a reason for this to be happening?

---

I just set up a second admin user account on a fresh install of Mac OS X Lion and now when I try to clear the terminal, I get the following error...

```
Hristo $ clear
terminals database is inaccessible
```

This is a problem for both user accounts and I have no idea why. I'm not sure if this is much help, but here is what `$TERM` is set to...

```
Hristo $ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Any thoughts as to why this might be happening?

Let me know if I need to show my `.bashrc` or `.profile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your `TERM` value isn't recognized. You are probably setting the TERM value in your `.profile` (or similar) or you've got missing/corrupt files or invalid permissions in `/usr/share/terminfo/`.

Comment: hmm... I am not setting the TERM value in neither account's `.profile` and the permissions are 755 for all directories under `/usr/share/terminfo/` with owners `root wheel`

Comment: Run `echo $TERM` and tell me what it says.

Comment: @bahamat... that is in my post above. it says "xterm-256color"

Comment: Sorry, don't know why I missed that. Look at `/usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-256color`. Does it exist? Is it readable by you? Try changing your `TERM` to `xterm` and see if the problem persists.

Comment: `xterm-256color` does not exist and how would I change TERM to xterm?

Comment: The default in Lion is now xterm-256color. It's not something you did by accident, but I don't know why you're missing xterm-256color.

Comment: @Hristo, you can change the value of the `TERM` environment variable using Terminal's preferences: **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Advanced > Declare terminal as**. However, that menu only contains a subset of the available Xterm-related values. `xterm` only declares eight colors, which may significantly reduce color support in some applications, and `xterm-color` is not recommended except as a last resort. You can directly edit the TerminalType value in Terminal preferences via `defaults` or by editing com.apple.Terminal.plist directly.

Comment: Or you can `export TERM=xterm` in your shell startup file (e.g., ~/.bashrc).

Answer (score 7):

In Mac OS X Lion 1.07, Terminal now supports 256 colors, Background Color Erase (BCE) and some other features that make it more compatible with modern xterm, and the default value for $TERM is now xterm-256color instead of xterm-color (which represents an older branch of xterm with less functionality).

If you upgrade to Lion, any settings profiles that used xterm-color will use the new default. (All "Declare terminal as" does is set the value of $TERM, by the way.)

The error you're seeing indicates that the appropriate terminfo files for xterm-256color are either missing or inaccessible. You might try installing Lion again. Also, some people have reported that installing Xcode 4 on Lion can cause this problem.

You can test the validity of xterm-256color with the following shell command:

```
infocmp xterm-256color
```

This will either display an error or the appropriate terminfo values for xterm-256color, and, if found, it displays the pathname to the terminfo file it used.

Comment: running `$ infocmp xterm-256color` results in `infocmp: couldn't open terminfo file (null).` So I'm assuming something is wrong. I did install Xcode 4 but can't definitively say that it was the reason. Any suggestions? I would prefer not to reinstall Lion...

Comment: ... seems to work now... no idea what changed

Comment: I'm missing the profile for xterm-256color under /usr/share/terminfo/78 as well.  For now setting the default terminal back to xterm-color.

Comment: Using xterm-color is not recommended, as it describes an older, less capable branch of Xterm. If xterm-256color isn't installed, the next best $TERM values to try are xterm-88color, xterm-16color and xterm, in that order.

Comment: Terminal's "Declare terminal as" preference setting only contains `xterm`, `xterm-color` and `xterm-256color`. However, you can set it to other values by editing preferences with `defaults write com.apple.Terminal …` or by editing the com.apple.Terminal.plist preferences file. Or, you can change the value of `TERM` in your shell startup file, e.g., put `export TERM=xterm-88color` in ~/.bashrc (and if you haven't already done this, create a ~/.bash_profile that runs ~/.bashrc).

Answer (score 4):

xterm-256color should be present in `/usr/share/terminfo/78`.

Run this command and double check if it's there:

```
ls -laR /usr/share/terminfo
```

In the past, there were issues with Xcode messing up permissions to a huge degree. Worst case scenario, use disk utility and repair your permissions. You will need to boot from an install DVD and verify/repair your boot partition.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS Catalina I placed this inside the .bash_profile:

```
export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
```

Then sourced it:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Bang, `clear` now works again.

Answer (score 0):

Super easy to fix...

Create a symbolic link so the computer sees xterm-color as xterm-256color:

[AS ROOT]

`ln -s /usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-color /usr/share/terminfo/78/xterm-colorxterm-256color`

Answer (score 0):

I also came across this error on the new Mac. In my case, the error is caused by using "`conda create -c rdkit -n rdkit-env rdkit`" ([source link](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Install.html)) to create a conda environment with the rdkit for Python3.7 on Mac. Otherwise, the clear command works fine for the other conda or virtual Python environments.

Adding the following line to ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc solves the issue for me ([source link](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1368)):

```
export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
```

N.B.: I did not try @Christopher Brunner's symbolic link solution which requires sudo, but sudo command is not always available for someone who works with university computer or HPC computers.

In addition, for those who also have the issue about "[cannot repeat last command in python interpreter shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289937/how-to-repeat-last-command-in-python-interpreter-shell)" or "[Seeing escape characters when pressing the arrow keys in python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893053/seeing-escape-characters-when-pressing-the-arrow-keys-in-python-shell/26356378#26356378)", as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np, pandas as pd
import rdkit, pubchempy>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pubchempy'
>>> ^D
```

A general solution is you would need to install py-readline or deadline package for python.

```
conda install readline # for conda environment for Python
pip3 install deadline
```